# Fix actionbar tab width

Tags: android, android-tabs

The layout below has 4 tabs and I have to scroll through to open the different tabs. Is there a way to fix the tab width so that all 4 tabs can be displayed on screen?

[image: Tabs on actionbar]

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed tabs instead of scrollable ones.

See
http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html
and
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html
(FragmentPagerAdapter vs. FragmentStatePagerAdapter)

But keep in mind that different users have different screen sizes and at some point the content of your tabs can't get any smaller without becoming unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The action bar tab has a build in padding of 16 dip for left and right.

`<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabView" parent="">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_tab_indicator_ab_holo</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">80dip</item>
    </style>`

In order to override the padding you need to override those properties:

`<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.MY_STYLE" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_MY_STYLE_light</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">1dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">1dip</item>
</style>`

This fixed the problem to me.